# Is it possible to pull information from database to env file in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, environment-variables

Is it possible to bring a value from the database into the env file in Laravel as I have given in the example?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4yY2.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can update variable when data is updated in database.

You can refer this code as example.

```
$name1 = 'SITE_NAME';

file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
    $name1 . '=' . env($name1), $name1 . '=' . $value1, file_get_contents($path)
));
```

But is is advised you to do note update `.env` frequently. It may cause security issue.